# i am trying to install mongoose to my nodejs project but fail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose, installation

I have tried to include the mongoose dependency in order to do that I have to tried to install the mongoose in my nodejs project. It failed with the following error message:

```
"npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
'....0","standard-version'"
```

Comment: can you show your package.json?

Comment: {
  "name": "hms",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hospital mangemant system with node",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "devstart": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "yamlak kassahun and Natinale Solomon",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.1"
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try npm cache clean --force
and than try npm install mongoose --save

This cleans the cache so you will lose your cache memory.
But some times the cache memory causes the problem so this might help.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.